# Why do the Bajorans own DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, laws, space-station

There are a number of issues at play here:

- DS9 is in orbit around Bajor (before "Emissary")
- The Cardassians built DS9, using Cardassian design, in orbit around an occupied planet
- DS9 is, at least to some degree movable ("Emissary")
- DS9 is a significant military asset

It seems a little odd to abandon something so valuable.

I'm wondering if there's canon discussion of how Bajor came to possess DS9.    Is it only because it was considered essentially immovable?  Were there any negotiations involved?   Any governing laws mentioned?   Did Cardassia ever refute the claim by Bajor?

Comment: Not sure if related, but the closest equivalent I can think of is that generally the US maintains possession of military bases (Japan, Korean, Cuba, Germany) even after it has no other military presence in those theatres.  (I'm people can poke holes in this analogy.)

Comment: If the station were moved it would no longer be an important asset (it is so because of its position near the wormhole, and pre-DS9 it wasn't even armed), plus the station was so run down that Miles O'Brien had to scavenge another similar station (Empok Nor) for parts. It probably wasn't worth salvaging to the Cardassians.

Comment: “DS9 is a significant military asset” — I’m not sure that’s established. It’s definitely an old ore-processing facility. I think Starfleet had to upgrade its weapons in ‘Emissary’ just to give it a chance at defending itself against a couple of ships. It also doesn’t seem warp-capable, so getting it somewhere else where they have ore to process probably isn’t worth the trouble for the Cardassians.

Comment: A better question is why the Cardassians didn't destroy it.

Comment: @Richard, as per Memory-Alpha, "Before departing, however, Cardassian soldiers rampaged across the station, removing or destroying a large portion of the station's equipment and killing several shop owners". They probably thought it would not be of much use after that (and IIRC they booby-trapped what was left, which to a certain mindset is more satisfying than simple destruction).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - The station itself is/was a sizable asset. I'm not seeing a good reason why they didn't just detonate it

Comment: @Richard, detonating the station would destroy simply the station, whereas leaving traps would kill people.  Apparently this was [standard Cardassian procedure regarding the abandonment of a facility](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Booby_trap).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Good find (re: Empok Nor) I like it

Comment: @Richard, perhaps destroying it would cause significant chance of de-orbiting debris,  and for whatever reason this was not considered acceptable.   Or it just wasn't considered worth the torpedo.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I don't think the Cardassians would be so shortsighted as to not see the station is a significant asset to a formerly space faring race trying to get back on its feet.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: was it a particularly significant asset even to the Bajorans though? It was once the wormhole showed up, but if that hadn’t happened it might well have ended up being nothing much but a big metal moon. The Bajorans were still having trouble feeding themselves during the run of the show. I’m not clear what use DS9 would have been to them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, this is like saying North Korea,  China,  or - heck - the United States has no use or value for an airport because it has starving people.

Comment: @ThePopMachine, that would depend on the state if the aiport. I'm in Germany, and when the Russians moved out from the GDR they did not blow up their garrisons, bunkers and airfields, and generally those have been more of a nuisance than an asset (too run down and stripped of everything useful to be of much use).

Comment: @EikePierstorff, it's a lot easier to build a new airstrip than a space station.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: kind of, but we’re talking about DS9. So: in the show, what was so valuable about DS9 to the Bajorans? If it wasn’t there, what would have been different?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, it's a jumping off point to renewed interstellar travel.   And they could use it as a drydock to build new ships.  It doesn't matter if they weren't ready for that yet.   It could have been five, ten,  or fifty years later.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: okay, so it might be valuable to the Bajorans in the future. Why would the Cardassians care particularly about that?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   Because they are spiteful militaristic imperialistic jerks?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:  Here's another argument that DS9 has intrinsic value:   If it's booby trapped and worthless, why didn't the Federation/Bajor just build a new space station?   Any argument for why they didn't is also an argument for why DS9 is valuable as is.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I’m not arguing DS9 has no value to anyone. Obviously the Federation might as well use a space station that’s already there, especially given how far from earth it is. But if the Cardassians *had* destroyed it, I think Starfleet *would* have just built their own. I therefore don’t think its destruction would have had much effect on Bajor (of course, excluding the wormhole from the equation, because it was unknown at the time).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:   I think you're seriously underestimating the cost and time to build (and therefore the worth) of a space station.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29948/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-thepopmachine).

Answer (score 12):

Terok Nor was an ore processing station built in orbit of Bajor during the Cardassian occupation of Bajor.

> In 2346, the Cardassians used Bajoran slave labor to build an orbital space station known as Terok Nor. - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Occupation_of_Bajor

It has no warp capability and has basic thrusters to maintain orbit. As an ore processing center (which used ore coming from Bajor and its moons) it had no strategic  value to the Cardassians, and would have been a hassle to take with them.

> As pointed out in a comment above, it seems to be standard procedure to [booby-trap abandoned installations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Booby_trap) rather than destroy them. - [Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104464/why-do-the-bajorans-own-ds9/104466#comment242971_104466)

Comment: As pointed out in a comment above, it seems to be standard procedure to [booby-trap abandoned installations](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Booby_trap) rather than destroy them.

Comment: Also, it only became a significant asset with the discovery of the wormhole. Before that, its only purpose was as a base for the federation to help/assimilate bajor.

Comment: Dukat, at least, was hoping that Cardassia would eventually be able to return.  No point in destroying an expensive space station if there's any chance of eventually getting it back.  (Presumably, that's also the reason why booby-trapping rather than destroying abandoned installations is standard procedure.)

Answer (score 10):

Regarding your observation,

> *"It seems a little odd to abandon something so valuable"*,

O'Brien says,

> *"The Cardassians took every component of value."*

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/401.htm))

Comment: Short and sweet, yet completely addresses the question - excellent: +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that DS9: "Emissary" ever explicitly states that the Cardassians **gave** Bajor the station, which suggests that Bajor claimed it at salvage.

This, by itself does not really answer the question of why the Cardassians **left** it, however. The closest we can come to a canonical answer to **that** is DS9: "Empok Nor", where we discover that the Cardassians seem to make a habit of simply abandoning their space habitats when they no longer have a use for them, sometimes going so far as to booby trap them against alien invasion, and thus safeguarding the possibility of eventual re-occupation.

Politically, Cardassia probably didn't feel that they could go that far with *Terok Nor*, given the scrutiny they were already under by the Federation, with whom they had only just recently concluded a treaty. Bajor's explicit request for Federation assistance would have magnified this aspect. Even if Cardassia had chosen to booby-trap it on their way out, clever people like O'Brien would have successfully dismantled the traps eventually.

More generally, constructing a space habitat is a fairly large undertaking. Once constructed, one does not simply scuttle it without good reason--particularly not in orbit of a populated planet, where the resulting pieces could be expected to de-orbit and make violent impacts upon the surface. Hauling away components for recycling would be problematic--*Star Trek* doesn't often seem to care much about mass, but volume would be a concern, certainly. Leaving the structure for someone else's use, or for their own later reuse (as in the case of "Empok Nor") costs nothing by comparison.